# How to define style for NA values in a reactable

Tags: r, na, reactable

I would like to apply a style to one of the vectors in a reactable output; yet some of my dataframes include some NA values and ColDef(... style function(value)) [see code below] seems to not allow to exclude NA or apply specific format to these records.

I have tried to add an else to the code below, using na.omit but cannot find a good solution (except forcing NA to 0 for ex). Any suggestion? Thanks!

```
reac0 <-
  reactable(prod0,
            columns = list(
            yrmon = colDef(name = "Period", style = cell_style(font_weight="bold")),
            Growth_Memb = colDef(name = "Members' Growth", format = colFormat(percent = TRUE, digits = 1),
                                 **style = function(value) {
                                   color <- if (value >= 0) {
                                     "#008000"
                                   } else if (value < 0) {
                                     "#e00000"
                                   }  
                                   {
                                     list(color = color) 
                                   }  
                                 }**
                                 )),
         theme = nytimes(),
         defaultPageSize = 12,
         pagination = FALSE
)
```